# How can I create a new column in an existing dataframe, fill it with na and specify its dtype to be int64?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe, and I would like to create an extra row and fill it with `NA` and also specify the `dtype` of the column to be `int64`. How would I do this?

e.g.
dataframe:

```
 col1    col2    
  5       's'
  7       'g'
  6       'f'
```

Let's say I want to add a new column called `new_col` and populate it with `NA` and specify the dtype to be int64.

I tried something like:

```
df['new_col'].fillna().dtype('int64')
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

The desired output is:

```
col1    col2     new_col
  5       's'      na
  7       'g'      na
  6       'f'      na
```

I can't show the desired dtype of `new_col` but I would like it to be `int64`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
df['new_col'] = np.nan
df['new_col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['new_col'], errors='coerce').astype('int', errors='ignore')
```